# вывод значения из value

Tags: javascript

Имею такой скрипт, он работает:

```
{literal}
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function changelicense() {
                    var licensetype = document.getElementById("licensetype").value;
                    if (licensetype == "regular") {
                      chooseLicence('regular', '**{$item.price|string_format:"%.0f"}**', '**{$item.prepaid_price|string_format:"%.0f"}**', 'block')
                    }
                    if (licensetype == "extended") {
                      chooseLicence('extended', '**{$item.extended_price|string_format:"%.0f"}**', '**{$item.extended_price|string_format:"%.0f"}**', 'none')
                    }
                } 
            </script>
            {/literal}
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы значение {$item.price|string_format:"%.0f"} писалось цифрами, как ему и положено? Пока получаю в значении именно вот эту надпись

Comment: Т.е. формат php реально воткнуть в js?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых - проверте сработает ли изменение ординарных кавычек ' на двойные ".
Во вторых - php исполняется на сервере, до того, как вообще можно исполнять javascript. Понятное дело, можно извратиться и придумать обход, но это будет не правильно немного. В принципе, зависит от задачи конечно...